# Ramdisk boot messages do not display correctly when boot messages are enabled. Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: boot, grub2

I edited `/etc/default/grub` and changed the line:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`

Then ran `sudo update-grub` and rebooted.

Ramdisk messages display like this during boot:

[image]

But the boot messages display correctly:

[image]

If I go into "recovery mode", Ramdisk boot messages display correctly.
Is there a setting I am missing? I did not have this problem when I was
running Ubuntu 18.04.6.

As requested, Here is my CPU info:

`inxi -C`

```
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Celeron N3050 bits: 64 type: MCP 
  L2 cache: 1024 KiB 
  Speed: 547 MHz min/max: 480/2160 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 538 2: 480
```

Comment: Does your notebook use an Intel or AMD graphics adapter at boot?

Comment: @matigo I am going into "uncharted territory" here. What command should I use to find that out?

Comment: Do you have multiple graphics devices in your notebook? If you're using an Intel chip with onboard graphics, chances are you are using the built-in graphics. If it's an AMD processor, then you're likely – though not guaranteed – that you're using the dedicated graphics device 

Comment: @matigo Can you answer my previous question to your comment before we move on? If not, My notebook is a Acer Aspire One, model AO1-431. It of course has a built in graphics display, but also has a builtin HDMI interface, which I leave disconnected at boot time. There are no other graphic devices. Furthermore, there have been no hardware changes since my upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04.6 - I have updated my question with requested information. Thank you for your inquires!

Comment: [Based on the spec list from Acer](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/CA/content/model/NX.SHGAA.004), your system has integrated graphics. That means that if you are following the answer below, you would add `i915` to the `modules` file 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely need to add the name of your video driver module to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`:

0. Edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` with `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo {editor of choice} /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice}` with your editor of choice.</sup>
1. Add the name of your video driver module to the end of the file. Here is a short list outlining the most common values:

   | Name | Graphics Adapter |
   | --- | --- |
   | `amdgpu` | for modern AMD-based systems (use `radeon` if you have something from before 2010 or need the legacy ATI driver) |
   | `i915` | for Intel graphics |
   | `nouveau` | for the open-source Nouveau driver |
   | `mgag200` | for the old-school Matrox graphics |
   | `nvidia nvidia_modeset nvidia_uvm nvidia_drm` | for Nvidia ... because why have one option when you can have four? |
2. Save the file and exit
3. Update `initramfs`:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
4. Reboot

This will give you everything you need.

---

**Note for people using full disk encryption:**

If you've also removed `quiet` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, you will have a very 90's era experience when unlocking the volume. The nice password screen is replaced with a simple text-based "Enter password" after some of the preliminary boot messages are displayed.

Comment: +1 for your answer. Just for the record, I am not using encryption. Your answer provided a partial solution to the problem. ramdisk boot messages still start with hieroglyphic messages then switch to human readable messages. I am still confused to why a OS upgrade (without a hardware change) would necessitate a configuration change to `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` Nonetheless, your solution is acceptable and safe for a live system. (I do not run VM, one mistake would destroy my system)